# Relational Store and Cube Inspection/Reflection

Tags: java, schema, activepivot

Relational stores and cubes are defined in ActivePivot through the various XML configuration files available, like Formats.csv, LoadInstructions.csv, WhatverCube.xml, and SchemaFields.xml. Can the configuration information specified in these files be accessed through an ActivePivot API after being parsed and loaded, or do we have to parse, load and examine these files ourselves to know the tables, fields, dimensions and measures defined in the currently active relational stores and cubes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete and detailed definition of your ActivePivot instances (and also of the schema) can be retrieved at runtime from the ActivePivot Manager:

```
IManagerDescription IActivePivotManager.getDescription();
List<ISchemaInstanceDescription> IManagerDescription.getSchemas();
ISchemaDescription ISchemaInstanceDescription.getSchemaDescription();
List<IActivePivotInstanceDescription> getActivePivotInstanceDescriptions();
IActivePivotDescription IActivePivotInstanceDescription.getActivePivotDescription();
...
```

Those definitions are also exposed through the Administration Service, available in Java or as a web service:

```
IManagerDescription IAdministrationService.retrieveManagerDescription();
```

For more details, have a look at the online javadoc ( http://support.quartetfs.com/documentation/javadoc/ )

You can also retrieve information about the Relational Stores using the java API. You access stores through the store universe:

```
IRelationalStore IStoreUniverse.get("MyStore");
Map<String,IField> IRelationalStore.getFields();
String[] IRelationalStore.getKeyFields();
Map<String,IRelationalJoin> IRelationalStore.getJoins();
...
```